# UniSwap Error - The token cannot be transferred. There may be an issue with the output token

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

https://etherscan.io/token/0xe0e00941dc0a4b0ebf9738b6d9a9d319cac8fd55 We deployed a few minutes ago and people are complaining that if you buy more than 0.005 worth of ETH they get the error "The token cannot be transferred. There may be an issue with the output token". What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Wondering if you ever figured out what this was in the end?

Comment: Thanks, lowering my ETH investment made the transaction go through.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your _maxTxmount limit (max per buy) was worried about investors in amounts larger than that.